# ActiveMq Broken pipe exception

Tags: activemq-classic

I am running an application which will produce JSON data to `activemq` and another process which will consume it and do some processing on this data. But as the JSON data which I am producing to the queue becomes larger in size I am getting `broken pipe exception`.Is there any limit in size of data which I can store/produce into activeMQ ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can configure a max frame size on the transport connector in ActiveMQ. By default in recent versions, it's around 100MB. Anyway, when you have that size of messages, you should think about splitting your data into smaller chunks.

Check out the ActiveMQ logs as well, maybe you have a clue there if it's a frame size limit that is hit or some other thing. Broken pipe simply means that the connection is broken by some reason, so that message does not say much.